# add unseen logic to readonly state redux - react

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have normalized events looks like the following:

```
"entities":{
"events":{
 "123":{
   ... data
 }
 "124":{
   ...data
 }
}}
```

I am showing the list on a simple material ui list

now when clicking on a button any new item in the list is now "unseen" and should not be auto-selected

do I need to add "unseen": true/ false. to the basic normalize data?  and then dispatch an update each time there is a new event? so it will looks like:

```
"entities":{
"events":{
 "123":{
   ... data
   unseen:false
 }
 "124":{
   ...data
   unseen: true
 }
}}
```

or it's better to hold a new list of unseen events ?
I am looking for a better way to handle it

do I need to change the read-only state in that case  ?  because now I am only updating a full object

redux state:

```
export interface EventsEntities {
  events: {
    [id: string]: Event;
  };
}
export interface EventState {
  readonly entities: EventsEntities;
  selectedItem: string | null;
  readonly result: string[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every value in the Redux state is assumed to be read-only, so you don't need to remove it in both cases.

You can change the `unseen` property using a Redux action like

```js
{
  type: 'toggle-unseen-event',
  eventId: '123',
  unseen: true
}
```

and handle it in reducer like this:

```js
function eventsReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...
    case 'toggle-unseen-event':
      return {
        ...state,
        events: {
          ...state.events,
          [action.eventId]: {
            ...state.events[action.eventId],
            unseen: action.unseen
          }
        }
      }
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, we're not mutating the event objects, so it can be readonly.

---

The best design for your Redux state depends on how and where you want to consume the data.

If there are components in which you are using events data only (but not `unseen`), then it's better to keep unseen events list in a separate place in the Redux state so that changing `unseen` property doesn't cause re-rendering of components which don't care about it.

But if you use `unseen` property everywhere you are using events data, then it's better to keep them in the same place so that you don't need merging unseen list and events data every time.

Comment: I have a list component that shows the list of events and there I need the unseen

also, I have selected Item that every other component used

Comment: In this case, you can simply keep `unseen: true/false` in your events and dispatch an action to set its value.

Comment: and how I handle the read-only state? it is possible to update specif param?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the objects without removing readonly. I will edit the answer and let me know if it's clear or not.